# Align Listbox, Button and Labels side by side

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am trying to align listbox, button and the labels side by side as shown in the figure but this is not working.

Basically I am dragging and dropping the controls side bar of visual studio and dropping them to webpage. But I am not able to align them as shown below.

Can somebody give advice to achieve this?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET framework 4.5.
[image]

Comment: You might want to use a table for that

Comment: Bearing in mind that asp.net will eventually render to HTML - may I recommend [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your figure shows the controls mis-aligned. If you want them aligned, eg Button on the same "line" as label2, I'd place all of them in a 5x3 table.

If you don't want them aligned, place them in a generic div, and add classes to them. Then in the css, set the div to position:relative, and position: absolute the elements as you want.